# Proguard preserve name of classes and packages but obfuscate fields and methods

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

Proguard preserves name of classes and packages but obfuscates fields and methods. In my mapping file I see that all packages and names of files remain the same but we don't need it. My Proguard's file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-allowaccessmodification

-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

-repackageclasses "com.example"
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Serviceлу
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

#your package path where your gson models are stored
-keep class com.example.model.** { *; }
```

In the meantime our other project with the same config works fine. All names of packages and classes renamed. Any suggestions are welcome.